# How to store search data in redis db for caching to gain maximum performance improvement

Tags: caching, redis, memcached, in-memory-database

We are implementing a online book store where the user can search books by filter,price,
author, sorting etc..Since we have million's of records in database(mysql) the search query
becomes slow. SO improve performance we are planning to implement caching mechanism using redis . BUt i am struggling to determine how to store the search data in redis db.
For example:-

If the search criteria is below:

{
searchFilter:
[

```
       {
          "field":"title",
      "operator" : "LIKE",
          "value" :  "JAVA"
       }

     ]
```

}

Then we will fetch data from from mysql db using above json. Then we are storing the data received in redis server.
In redis server we are using above json as "key" and all the books as value i.e
:

{searchFilter:[{"field":"title","operator" : "LIKE","value" :  "JAVA"}]} : booksList

Now say some other user again fired a search request as below

{

searchFilter:
[

```
       {
          "field":"title",
      "operator" : "LIKE",
          "value" :  "JAVA"
       },
   {
          "field":"price",
      "operator" : "GREATER_THAN",
          "value" :  "500"
       },
       {
          "field":"price",
      "operator" : "GREATER_THAN",
          "value" :  "500"
       }


     ]
```

}
Then again we will fetch data from from mysql db using above json. Then we are storing the data received in redis server so that for next request with same search critria
we will get data from redis cache.
In redis server we are using above json as "key" and all the books as value i.e
:

{searchFilter:[{"field":"title","operator" : "LIKE","value" :  "JAVA"},{"field":"price","operator" : "GREATER_THAN","value" :  "500",},{"field":"price","operator" : "GREATER_THAN","value" :  "500"}]} : booksList

So my question is using the json search criteria as key in redis is good idea?
If yes, then for every search request criteia having any small difference  if we store the data in redis then caching server will consume lot of memeory.
So what is the ideal aproach to design our redis cache server to gain maximum performance ?

Comment: You might want to explode [Redisearch](https://oss.redis.com/redisearch/) or consider a fully fledged search engine solution like Solr or ElasticSearch.

Comment: ^^Explore, not "explode" :)

Comment: I agree with @nitrin0 here, Redis is a key-value store and not suited for your use case. You'd have to define and create keys for _every possible search string_ and store the search and results in Redis. For millions of records like you said, this is pretty impractical. In addition to [Solr](https://solr.apache.org/) and [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/elasticsearch/) I'd also recommend [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/products/search-and-discovery/hosted-search-api/) and [MeiliSearch](https://www.meilisearch.com/). These are all purpose-built for _searching_.